# Laravel pagination broke on GoDaddy Production server

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, server, pagination

I have just uploaded my laravel application to my godaddy server and everything works apart from my 'search' functionality and 'pagination' which I presume are related to the same problem, being the URI. I thought maybe it is a .htaccess problem but if so I am unaware of how I can rectify this?

I tried deleting the config cache and it did not solve it.

.htaccess in public_html

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

.htaccess in laravel root

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I am using 'variable->links()' to output the pagination links with 'paginate(11).

I hope somebody can be of any assistance which would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted my research skills and managed to find a fix using the .htaccess found
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403519/laravel-4-pagination-not-working-links-are-ok-but-shows-all-results-in-each-page` here.